# bootstrap 3 collapse show and hide overlapping eachother

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website that is using bootstrap 3 and is doing an collapse panel when images are clicked.  I have code in place that watches for the 'show' event that will 'hide' all panels.  The issue im having is that the transition animation is not waiting for eachother to be completed resulting in some weird animation happening.  example page is here (  http://urbantimber.ca/newsite/product-flooring.html).

my function looks like:

```
    $(function () {
        var active = true;
        $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            if (active) $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
        });
    });
```

I have also tried to negate the transition by setting the speed to 0.001s but the blip still shows.

looking for any ideas on how to watch that the animation is completed before the show event is finished.  im thinking it needs to be a click event that happens before the show even starts but im not sure how to go about this.  any ideas or comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you're not better off just creating your own implementation.  You're not really using any of the 'accordion' like functionality.  Perhaps it would be easier to just have a click event handler attached to each of your images that checks if the details panel is displayed, if not, you would just display it using jquery show method. If it is displayed already, you could just replace the panel html with the item's details. (btw, nice looking site).